# How to create a Javascript object with index and values with variables?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I have a problem in my javascript code, i need to create an object with variables and those variables being objects too. Explanation:

I need this in my javascript code (similar to a Json structure):

```
var myObj = {
   variableOne: {
             variableOneA: 'someValue',
             variableOneB: 'someValue'
         }
   variableTwo: {
             variableTwoA: 'someValue',
             variableTwoB: 'someValue'
         }
   variableThree: {
             variableThreeA: 'someValue',
             variableThreeB: 'someValue'
         }
 }
```

Now, my problem with this is that in Js i cannot do a 'push' method to an object and i can only add one level of variables to my object doing this:

```
myObj.variableOne = 'someValue';
```

Can anyone help me please? i believe the resolution could be easy but i am new to Js.

Comment: `myObj.variableOne.variableOneA = 'someValue`' - you mean like this? You can access each deeper level with the `.` character. Alternatively, if it's a list, why not use an array instead? `myObj.variableOne = ['someValue', 'someValue']`, etc.

Comment: You can assign a new object to a property: `myObj.variableOne = {variableOneA:"somevalue"}`. You can make it as complex as you want. Actually our first snippet is valid js that would give you an object with the wanted structure

Comment: What exactly do you expect "push to the object" to do, automatically create that object and put the `someValue` in the `variableOneA`? If yes, then how would it know the name property `variableOneA` if you're not specifying it anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to access your object in Javascript.

```
var myObj = {
   variableOne: {
             variableOneA: 'oneA',
             variableOneB: 'oneB'
         }
   variableTwo: {
             variableTwoA: 'twoA',
             variableTwoB: 'twoB
         }
   variableThree: {
             variableThreeA: 'threeA',
             variableThreeB: 'threeB'
         }
 }
```

You can use "dot" to access a particular level of your object.

```
const valueVariableOneA = myObj.variableOne.variableOneA
console.log(valueVariableOneA) // output => "oneA"
```

You can use the square brackets in replacement of dot. Square brackets are usefull when you want to create an object's key with dash (eg: "cool-key")

```
const valueVariableThreeB = myObj['variableThree']['variableThreeB']
console.log(valueVariableThreeB) // output => "threeB"
```

You can also use the destructuration to access particular value

```
// Get value of variableTwoA key

const { variableTwoA } = myObj.variableTwo // first way
const { variableTwo : { variableTwoA } } = myObj // second way

console.log(variableTwoA) // output => "twoA"
```

Now to add a **key** to a nested object you can use either dot or square brackets method. Here's how to add key on the first level.

```
myObj.variableFour = { variableFourA: 'fourA', variableFourB: 'fourB' }
myObj['variableFour'] = { variableFourA: 'fourA', variableFourB: 'fourB' }

// add key on nested object

myObj.variableOne.variableOneC = 'oneC'
myObj['variableOne']['variableOneC'] = 'oneC'

// you can mix both
myObj['variableOne'].variableOneC = 'oneC'
myObj.variableOne['variableOneC'] = 'oneC'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats it!!

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
myObj.variableOne['someValue'] = 'new value';
```